# Is a good practive to take a RANDOM number from the "decimals" of different token prices in solodity?

Tags: random, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I was wondering if a good idea is to take a RANDOM number from the "decimals" of different token prices? the market is actually random, that's why it can't be predicted with total assertion.

I would like to know if this could be good practice or not. If this is not a good practice, why?

Answer (score 1):

The number won't be random, but it will pseudorandom, or guessable.

Any miner or MEV bot can easily access this information.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, we decided to use a signed service that provides randoms. The side is random.org ( https://api.random.org/json-rpc/4/signed ). This is a centralized service but you can verify the origin of the random using different methods and mechanisms. Recommended.